# XML Schema restriction defined by document being validated

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

Is there a way for an XML schema to define something like the following where the codes used in `<item>` elements are defined *by the document author* in the `<validCodes>` element. These codes themselves may be restricted to an enumeration or a simple regex match but that's not important here.

```
<validCodes>
  <code>AA</code>
  <code>BB</code>
</validCodes>
...
<item code="AA"> VALID </item>
<item code="BB"> VALID </item>
<item code="AB"> INVALID </item>
```

To rephrase this, I want to allow authors of a configuration file to define their own restrictions in XML without having to define it in terms of a schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### XSD 1.0

Your constraint cannot be expressed.

### XSD 1.1

Your constraint can be expressed via an assertion:

```
<xs:assert test="every $c in item/@code satisfies $c = validCodes/code"/>
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<r>
  <validCodes>
    <code>AA</code>
    <code>BB</code>
  </validCodes>
  <item code="AA"> VALID </item>
  <item code="BB"> VALID </item>
  <item code="AB"> INVALID </item>
</r>
```

**XSD**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           vc:minVersion="1.1">
  <xs:element name="r">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="validCodes">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="code" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="item" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
              <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute name="code" type="xs:string"/>
              </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
     <xs:assert test="every $c in item/@code satisfies $c = validCodes/code"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I was fairly certain it couldn't be in 1.0 but wanted another opinion. Oh well, fairly easy custom validation step.

Comment: It can't be done directly in 1.0, but you can for example define an enumeration type as an external entity and incorporate it into the schema using an entity reference, allowing different users of the schema to incorporate different versions of the code list.